# call function after "loop" function for multiple elements is finished in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, loops, animation

I've searched this site for a solution but couldn't find something to extract for my purpose.

I have two functions.
The first function fades in multiple elements in delay to each other until every element is faded in. Now I want to start the second function after the first is done with every element. I've tried with `.done()`, `.when()` or `.promise()` but could figure out a solution.

(the fiddle below is way simplified to show my problem. The site I'm working on is more complex, therefor I need a solution for calling function after function and not a `setTimeout()` or something else.)

```
var v = $(".box");
var cur = 0;

var first = function () { 
    function fadeInNextLI() {
        v.eq(cur++).fadeIn(200);
        if(cur != v.length) setTimeout(fadeInNextLI,100);
    }
    fadeInNextLI();
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
};

var second = function () {
    alert('done');
};

first().done(second)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c633f5w8/3/

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to rewrite it all but you have some necessary stuff. It illustrates the use of the fadeIn callback.

https://jsfiddle.net/c633f5w8/4/

```
var v = $(".box");
var cur = 0;
var len = v.length;
console.log(len);
var first = function () { 
    function fadeInNextLI() {
        if(cur+1 == len){
            v.eq(cur++).fadeIn(200,'swing',finish);
        } else {
        v.eq(cur++).fadeIn(200);
              if(cur != v.length) setTimeout(fadeInNextLI,100);
        }
              /*
              this doesn't work
              if(cur === v.length) return $.Deferred().resolve();
              */
    }
    fadeInNextLI();
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
};

function finish() {
    alert('done');
};

first();
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery fadeIn already allows to chain functions. Structure is like this:

```
$().fadeIn(duration, function(){//this will be triggered once fadeIn is completed});
```

You could chain your fadeIn using a recursive function and validate each time a fadeIn is completed if you should fadeIn or call another function. Like this:

```
    var v = $(".box");
    var cur = 0;

    fade_next($('.box:first-child'))

    var second = function () {
        alert('done');
    };

    function fade_next(cur) {
        cur.fadeIn(200, function () {
            if (cur.next().length) {
                fade_next(cur.next())
             } else {
                 second();
             }
         });
    }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rpnzz4mr/3/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could find was to count the divs, then just trigger after the final div animation:

```js
var v = $(".box");
var cur = 0;

var first = function () { 
 function fadeInNextLI() {
        v.eq(cur++).fadeIn(200).promise().then(cur == $('div').length ? second : function(){});
     if(cur != v.length) setTimeout(fadeInNextLI,100);
              /*
              this doesn't work
              if(cur === v.length) return $.Deferred().resolve();
              */
 }
 fadeInNextLI();
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
};

second = function () {
    alert('done');
};

first();
```

```css
.box{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.delay()` , `.promise()` , `$.when()` , `$.map()`

```js
$.when.apply($, $.map($(".box"), function fadeInNextLI(el, index) {
  return $(el).delay(100 * index, "fx").fadeIn(200 * index).promise("fx");
})).then(function() { 
  alert("done");
});
```

```css
.box {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c633f5w8/8/